# Alternative to module:status magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

In Magento 2 we can show all the modules and check whether they are active or not using 
`php bin/magento module:status`

What is the alternative in Magento 1.
Thanks in advance

Comment: try this: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun it's a tool for magento 1 that works as bin/magento in magento 2 with a lot of functionalies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command-line command equivalent for Magento 1.

You have two options to confirm:

**Backend**

`System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced`  - unfortunately this will only show enable / disable **Output**, not if the module is completely disabled.

**File Structure**

Module configurations are located at `app/etc/modules/`.  You will have to go through those modules and see which ones are `<active>`

Comment: Thanks, that is very annonying. In Magento 2 It is very clear

Comment: Yes Magento 2 is a vast improvement in some areas, command-line tools being one of them.  Makes some things much easier! (Please accept answer if it helped)

Comment: I tested the first one and It works , thanks .

Comment: Thanks, good luck!

Comment: And you the same if you find my question useful for another one make upvote for it

Answer (score 1):

This should be the right solution:

I suggest that you implement "netz98 magerun CLI tools for Magento 1" inside your magento root folder. (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)

Afterwards you are able to use command line snippets for example for refreshing indexes or in your case for checking disabled modules and their config.

You can find the full list of commands (for reference) below:

```
     ___ ___
 _ _/ _ ( _ )___ _ __  __ _ __ _ ___ _ _ _  _ _ _
| ' \_, / _ \___| '  \/ _` / _` / -_) '_| || | ' \
|_||_/_/\___/   |_|_|_\__,_\__, \___|_|  \_,_|_||_|
                           |___/
n98-magerun version 1.102.0 by netz98 GmbH

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help                 Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                Do not output any message
  -V, --version              Display this application version
      --ansi                 Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi              Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction       Do not ask any interactive question
      --root-dir[=ROOT-DIR]  Force magento root dir. No auto detection
      --skip-config          Do not load any custom config.
      --skip-root-check      Do not check if n98-magerun runs as root
      --developer-mode       Instantiate Magento in Developer Mode
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose       Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help                               Displays help for a command
  install                            Install magento
  list                               Lists commands
  mysql-client                       Opens mysql client by database config from local.xml
  open-browser                       Open current project in browser (experimental)
  script                             Runs multiple n98-magerun commands
  self-update                        Updates n98-magerun.phar to the latest version.
  selfupdate                         Updates n98-magerun.phar to the latest version.
  shell                              Runs n98-magerun as shell
  uninstall                          Uninstall magento (drops database and empties current folder or folder set via installationFolder)
 admin
  admin:notifications                Toggles admin notifications
  admin:user:change-password         Changes the password of a adminhtml user.
  admin:user:change-status           Set active status of an adminhtml user. If no option is set the status will be toggled.
  admin:user:create                  Create admin user.
  admin:user:delete                  Delete the account of a adminhtml user.
  admin:user:list                    List admin users.
 aoe
  aoe:cpc:clear                      Clears AOE class path cache
 cache
  cache:clean                        Clean magento cache
  cache:dir:flush                    Flush (empty) Magento cache directory
  cache:disable                      Disables magento caches
  cache:enable                       Enables magento caches
  cache:flush                        Flush magento cache storage
  cache:list                         Lists all magento caches
  cache:report                       View inside the cache
  cache:view                         Prints a cache entry
 category
  category:create:dummy              Create a dummy category
 cms
  cms:block:list                     List all cms blocks
  cms:block:toggle                   Toggle a cms block
 composer
  composer:diagnose                  Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
  composer:init                      Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
  composer:install                   Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  composer:require                   Adds required packages to your composer.json and installs them
  composer:search                    Search for packages
  composer:update                    Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  composer:validate                  Validates a composer.json and composer.lock
 config
  config:delete                      Deletes a store config item
  config:dump                        Dump merged xml config
  config:get                         Get a core config item
  config:search                      Search system configuration descriptions.
  config:set                         Set a core config item
 customer
  customer:change-password           Changes the password of a customer.
  customer:create                    Creates a new customer/user for shop frontend.
  customer:create:dummy              Generate dummy customers. You can specify a count and a locale.
  customer:delete                    Delete Customer/s
  customer:info                      Loads basic customer info by email address.
  customer:list                      Lists customers
 db
  db:console                         Opens mysql client by database config from local.xml
  db:create                          Create currently configured database
  db:drop                            Drop current database
  db:dump                            Dumps database with mysqldump cli client
  db:import                          Imports database with mysql cli client according to database defined in local.xml
  db:info                            Dumps database informations
  db:maintain:check-tables           Check database tables
  db:query                           Executes an SQL query on the database defined in local.xml
  db:status                          Shows important server status information or custom selected status values
  db:variables                       Shows important variables or custom selected
 design
  design:demo-notice                 Toggles demo store notice for a store view
 dev
  dev:class:lookup                   Resolves a grouped class name
  dev:code:model:method              Code annotations: Reads the columns from a table and writes the getter and setter methods into the class file for @methods.
  dev:console                        Opens PHP interactive shell with initialized Mage::app() (Experimental)
  dev:email-template:usage           Display database transactional email template usage
  dev:ide:phpstorm:meta              Generates meta data file for PhpStorm auto completion (default version : 2016.2+)
  dev:log                            Toggle development log (system.log, exception.log)
  dev:log:db                         Turn on/off database query logging
  dev:log:size                       Get size of log file
  dev:merge-css                      Toggles CSS Merging
  dev:merge-js                       Toggles JS Merging
  dev:module:create                  Create and register a new magento module.
  dev:module:dependencies:from       Show list of modules which depend on %s module
  dev:module:dependencies:on         Show list of modules which given module depends on
  dev:module:disable                 Disable a module or all modules in codePool
  dev:module:enable                  Enable a module or all modules in codePool
  dev:module:list                    List all installed modules
  dev:module:observer:list           Lists all registered observers
  dev:module:rewrite:conflicts       Lists all magento rewrite conflicts
  dev:module:rewrite:list            Lists all magento rewrites
  dev:module:update                  Update a Magento module.
  dev:profiler                       Toggles profiler for debugging
  dev:report:count                   Get count of report files
  dev:setup:script:attribute         Creates attribute script for a given attribute code
  dev:symlinks                       Toggle allow symlinks setting
  dev:template-hints                 Toggles template hints
  dev:template-hints-blocks          Toggles template hints block names
  dev:theme:duplicates               Find duplicate files (templates, layout, locale, etc.) between two themes.
  dev:theme:info                     Displays settings of current design on particular store view
  dev:theme:list                     Lists all available themes
  dev:translate:admin                Toggle inline translation tool for admin
  dev:translate:export               Export inline translations
  dev:translate:set                  Adds a translation to core_translate table. Globally for locale
  dev:translate:shop                 Toggle inline translation tool for shop
 eav
  eav:attribute:create-dummy-values  Create a dummy values for dropdown attributes
  eav:attribute:list                 Lists all EAV attributes
  eav:attribute:remove               Removes attribute for a given attribute code
  eav:attribute:view                 View informations about an EAV attribute
 extension
  extension:download                 Download magento-connect package
  extension:install                  Install magento-connect package
  extension:list                     List magento connection extensions
  extension:search                   List magento connection extensions
  extension:upgrade                  Upgrade magento-connect package
  extension:validate                 Reads Magento Connect Config, and checks that installed package files are really there
 index
  index:list                         Lists all magento indexes
  index:list:mview                   Lists all magento mview indexes
  index:reindex                      Reindex a magento index by code
  index:reindex:all                  Reindex all magento indexes
  index:reindex:mview                Reindex a magento index by code using the materialised view functionality
 local-config
  local-config:generate              Generates local.xml config
 media
  media:cache:image:clear            Clears image cache
  media:cache:jscss:clear            Clears JS/CSS cache
  media:dump                         Creates an archive with content of media folder.
 script
  script:repo:list                   Lists all scripts in repository
  script:repo:run                    Run script from repository
 sys
  sys:check                          Checks Magento System
  sys:cron:history                   Last executed cronjobs with status.
  sys:cron:list                      Lists all cronjobs
  sys:cron:run                       Runs a cronjob by job code
  sys:info                           Prints infos about the current magento system.
  sys:maintenance                    Toggles maintenance mode.
  sys:modules:list                   List all installed modules
  sys:setup:change-version           Change module setup resource version
  sys:setup:compare-versions         Compare module version with core_resource table.
  sys:setup:incremental              List new setup scripts to run, then runs one script
  sys:setup:remove                   Remove module setup resource entry
  sys:setup:run                      Runs all new setup scripts.
  sys:store:config:base-url:list     Lists all base urls
  sys:store:list                     Lists all installed store-views
  sys:url:list                       Get all urls.
  sys:website:list                   Lists all websites
```

For your case you should use the command `n98-magerun dev:module:list`. It'll then provide you with information about all the installed modules and their activation state, f.e.:

[image: Magento_modules_list]

Answer (score 0):

You could also just type a one-liner into the terminal (inside the magento directory):

```
grep -RRhB 1 "<active>1</active>\|<active>TRUE</active>\|<active>true</active>" app/etc/modules/
```

(for disabled extensions insert 0 and false/FALSE)

or for both enabled and disabled modules:

```
echo "" && echo "Enabled Modules:" && grep -RZhB 1 "<active>1</active>\|<active>TRUE</active>\|<active>true</active>" app/etc/modules/ && echo "" && echo "Disabled Modules" && grep -RZhB 1 "<active>0</active>\|<active>FALSE</active>\|<active>false</active>" app/etc/modules/
```